# Implementing a cancel edit in Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have an **ng-repeat** within a `gridController as gc` that I use to populate a Bootstrap table:

```
<div ng-repeat="(id, task) in gc.modelFilter(model.getModelAsDict())">
  <div ng-show="model.getTask(id).edit_active" class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="showDeleteModal(id)">Delete</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="gc.save(task)">Save</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="gc.cancel(task)">Cancel</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row datacell" ng-class="{'active': model.getTask(id).edit_active}">
    <div class="col-sm-1"><p contenteditable="true" ng-model="task.case_name"></p></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1"><p contenteditable="true" ng-model="task.title"></p>
    ....
  </div>
</div>
```

The div after the ng-repeat is used to conditionally show a set of buttons if that task has the property `edit_active` set to `true`. If that property is true, **ng-class** adds a custom class of `active` to the row and I use css to style that row as editable if it has an `active` class.

I have a custom directive for `contenteditable`:

```
app.directive("contenteditable", function() {

  return {

  restrict: "A",
  require: "ngModel",
  link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

    function read() {
      ngModel.$setViewValue(element.html());
    }

    ngModel.$render = function() {
      element.html(ngModel.$viewValue);
    };

    element.bind("blur keyup change", function() {
      scope.$apply(read);
    });

    function setRowActive(id) {
      scope.model.getTask(id).edit_active = true;
    }

    element.bind("click", function() {
      console.log('editing row id ' + scope.id);
      scope.$apply(setRowActive(scope.id));
    });
  }
};
```

});

This all works well as it allows a user to click on a Bootstrap row and edit the value. The save process is straightforward. However I am trying to determine how to implement the cancel process. if a user has clicked on a row and has edited a field.

By the time I get to the `gc.cancel()` function, the model value has been updated and all I have is the changed value. How can I restore the original value?

Comment: In a directive you can only duplicate the model and revert back on cancel. If you can consider moving your directive to a component (which you should) you can use one way data binding with $onChanges hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the other answers seem to recognise that in the custom directive, the `ngModelController` is available - which maintains the prior value. So doing a one-time only save to a underscore prefixed property allows the initial value to be saved on the object. Should the edit be cancelled, a check for prefixed properties can be done.

The `read()` function would look like this:

```
   function read() {
     // capture old value and save as __property
     var property_name = '__' + attrs.ngModel.split('.')[1];
     // if no prior property exists, add it
     if (!scope.task.hasOwnProperty(property_name)) {
       scope.task[property_name] = ngModel.$$lastCommittedViewValue;
     }

     ngModel.$setViewValue(element.html());
   }
```

So, if the `task.title` was edited, this would save the prior value as `task.__title`

Answer (score 1):

When you start editing, can you create a copy of the data and then you could reset all of the values when they cancel?

Answer (score 0):

i think that the answer to your situation is to separate the model from the view form the 2-way-bindings, meaning that you should create a service that returns you a duplication of the data-model, which you show and render in the view, and if the user click save you send the service to update the task, otherwise you re-ask for the task to load old data.

Comment: That would be functional but it would mean duplicating the entire model. There are many more columns than depicted in my code and a large number of rows.

Comment: than you should implement paging, and duplicate X rows at a time

Answer (score 0):

Pass both `id` and `task` for `edit` function and `cancel` function

```js
function gridController (){
 // your code here
  gc.editing_tasks = {}
  gc.edit = function(task, id){
    gc.editing_tasks.id = task // so if you are editing multiple task at a time, all of them can save here

    // you can use sessionStorage or localStorage instead of saving in an object (I prefer that)
  }
  
  gc.cancel = function (id, task){
    task = gc.editing_tasks.id
    
    delete gc.editing_tasks.id // no more needed
  }
 // your code here
}
```

**Alternative way**

```js
function gridController (){
 // your code here
  gc.editing_tasks = {}
  gc.edit = function(task, id){
    gc.editing_tasks.id = task // so if you are editing multiple task at a time, all of them can save here

    // you can use sessionStorage or localStorage instead of saving in an object (I prefer that)
  }
  
  gc.cancel = function (index){
    gc.modelFilter[index] = gc.editing_tasks.id //taking gc.modelFilter as your ng-repeated array
    
    delete gc.editing_tasks.id // no more needed
  }
 // your code here
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="gc.cancel($index)">Cancel</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no "out of the box" way to implement cancellation of an edit (nearly 4 years on, Angular 9)

Somewhere you need to take a copy of the original state and restore that when user clicks cancel - as noted by Jay

Answer (score -2):

```html
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary md-fab md-mini" ng-click="vm.detail($event, item)">
  <md-tooltip>
    EDIT
  </md-tooltip>
  <md-icon>edit</md-icon>
</md-button>
<md-button class="md-raised md-warn" ng-click="vm.cancel()">Cancel</md-button>
```

Comment: <md-button class="md-raised md-primary md-fab md-mini" ng-click="vm.detail($event, item)">
                                <md-tooltip>
                                    EDIT
                                </md-tooltip>
                                <md-icon>edit</md-icon>
                            </md-button>
 <md-button class="md-raised md-warn" ng-click="vm.cancel()">Cancel</md-button>